# What is best $1$ out $2$ oblivious transfer?

Tags: protocol-design, oblivious-transfer

There are a lot of oblivious transfer algorithm. What is the best? It would be good if it were malicious secure, but that is not necessary, if this make protocol very difficult/slow. This protocol should be not very difficult, but the most important it should be fast and has low communication complexity.

Comment: In the case of large scale, IKNP-style or PCG-style OTE framework can bring cheap overhead for computation, but not for communication due to the inherent characteristics of OT. As far as I know, the most efficient OT with low communication was [Ferret][1].


  [1]: https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/924